# Regex Boolean  Function in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that I would like to test to see if it is in the following format.

```
exactly seven alphabetical OR numerical characters, followed by a '_', followed by 
exactly five alphabetical OR numerical characters, followed by a '_', followed by 
exactly seven alphabetical OR numerical characters, followed by a '_', followed by 
exactly nine alphabetical OR numerical characters. 
No other characters should exist other then the above mentioned characters.
```

I would like a function that returns true if it matches the description or false if it does not match.

Edit: alpha and numeric characters can be mixed.

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work? If not, why not? -1 for not posting an initial attempt and "too localized" because, well, it really is :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{}` will allow you to specify how many times char can be repeated.

The `[]` lets you list possible characters where `-` specifies ranges of characters.

The `i` flag at the end makes it case-insensitive. `^` marks the start of the string and `$` marks the end. These prevent anything to be in front of behind of the match.

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{7}_[a-z0-9]{5}_[a-z0-9]{7}_[a-z0-9]{9}$/i', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression to match this would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}_[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}$
```

Brief overview of the syntax:

- `^` matches only the start of the string; `$` matches only the end.
- `[` and `]` denote characters to match. They can include ranges like `0-9`.
- `{` and `}` denote repetition of the previous thing a specific number of times.